# Is it possible to write a whole object in InfluxDB?

Tags: influxdb, telemetry

I'd like to AUTOMATICALLY write telemetry record set (aka a javascript multi-level object as follows) so that InfluxDB can retrieve individual values from the timestamp? (soh, soc etc. in this example)

```
const telemetry = { 
  createdAt: '2021-05-03 12:10:09',
  id: 'FOO',
  configuration: {
    version: '1.2.3',
    name: 'pepsr'
  },
  batteries: [
    '0': {
      soc: 90, 
      soh: 97, 
      eqCycles: 234
    },
    '1': {
      soc: 91, 
      soh: 96, 
      eqCycles: 237
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ValueField you can store the string object data in influx. You need to serialize your object store as string binary data.

I have implemented this in c# .net core api and its working perfectly. Make sure your object data size fall in the limit as per the defined limit.

```
Length limit 64KB
```

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/write_protocols/line_protocol_reference/#data-types

Comment: That is what I do now. But my question is how can I store it so that every single property could be fetch independently, without the need to deserialize

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca Influx db doesn't have that feature